# How to speed up fuzzy index matching in R (potentially using Rcpp)?

Tags: r, interpolation, rcpp, fuzzy-search

I am trying to look up a value from the given lookup table(lk_tbl) using, for the lack of a better word, fuzzy matching such as following:

```
lk_tbl <- structure(list(num = c(1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 
1.4), val = c(0.241970724519143, 0.229882140684233, 0.217852177032551, 
0.205936268719975, 0.194186054983213, 0.182649085389022, 0.171368592047807, 
0.16038332734192, 0.149727465635745)), .Names = c("num", "val"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

> lk_tbl
   num       val
1 1.00 0.2419707
2 1.05 0.2298821
3 1.10 0.2178522
4 1.15 0.2059363
5 1.20 0.1941861
6 1.25 0.1826491
7 1.30 0.1713686
8 1.35 0.1603833
9 1.40 0.1497275
```

Basically, the table pairs a number and its associated value. Now If I want to find the value associated with the number `1.22`, which is not in the lk_tbl, I want to do sort of interpolation.

```
fuzzy_lkup<- function(x) {
  matched_num <- lk_tbl %>% 
    filter(num==x)     # check for exact val

  if(nrow(matched_num) == 1 ) { # if the exact match exists
    return(matched_num$val)
  } 
  else {
  return(lk_tbl %>% 
    filter( x < num + 0.05, x > num -0.05 ) %>%
    .[["val"]] %>%
    mean())

  }
}


> fuzzy_lkup(1) # it returns the matched value
[1] 0.2419707
> fuzzy_lkup(1.22) # it does the interpolation
[1] 0.1884176

# for the vector, I can use vapply like this.
> vapply(c(1.22, 1.18, 1.24), fuzzy_lkup,numeric(1))
[1] 0.1884176 0.2000612 0.1884176
```

Ultimately, I want to do this for a long vector from the huge lookup table.

Now what I observed is  this process is prohibitly slow for the large lookup table So my question is

1. How would you speed this up? (vectorize this function?)
2. How would you solve this with Rcpp? Is Rcpp the right tool for this? how would you import the lookup table, what data structure would you use to solve this, and ultimately how do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, a potential approach could be:

```
ff = function(x, num, val)
{
    i = findInterval(x, num)  #map input to the lookup-table

    #make the appropriate vectors to interpolate
    nums = c(rbind(num[i], x, num[i + 1L]))
    vals = c(rbind(val[i], NA, val[i + 1L]))

    #if 'mean' is needed; i.e. 'f(1.22) == f(1.24)' etc, the following could be used:
    #nums = seq_along(vals) 

    ans = approx(nums, vals, xout = nums)$y[seq(2L, length(nums), 3L)]

    return(cbind(x, ans))
}
```

And an example:

```
ff(c(1.22, 1.18, 1.24, 1.05, 1.2, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24, 1.4, 1.5), lk_tbl$num, lk_tbl$val)
#         x       ans
# [1,] 1.22 0.1895713
# [2,] 1.18 0.1988861
# [3,] 1.24 0.1849565
# [4,] 1.05 0.2298821
# [5,] 1.20 0.1941861
# [6,] 1.22 0.1895713
# [7,] 1.23 0.1872639
# [8,] 1.24 0.1849565
# [9,] 1.40 0.1497275
#[10,] 1.50        NA
```

To address the second question, the above can, also, conveniently be transferred in C thanks to R's API:

```
ffC = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "numeric", num = "numeric", val = "numeric"), body = '
    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, LENGTH(x)));

    double *px = REAL(x), *pnum = REAL(num), *pval = REAL(val), *pans = REAL(ans);

    int n = LENGTH(num), flag;

    for(int i = 0, ind = 1; i < LENGTH(x); i++) {
        ind = findInterval(pnum, n, px[i], 0, 0, ind, &flag);

        pans[i] = ind == n ? (px[i] == pnum[n - 1] ? pval[n - 1] : NA_REAL) : 
             pval[ind - 1] + (pval[ind] - pval[ind - 1]) * 
                 ((px[i] - pnum[ind - 1]) / (pnum[ind] - pnum[ind - 1]));
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
', language = "C")
```

And benchmarking the two approaches:

```
NUM = seq(1, 100, 0.2)
set.seed(007)
VAL = runif(length(NUM))
X = sample(1:110, 1e5, TRUE) + sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 1e5, TRUE)

all.equal(ff(X, NUM, VAL)[, 2L], ffC(X, NUM, VAL))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff(X, NUM, VAL)[, 2L], ffC(X, NUM, VAL), times = 30)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
# ff(X, NUM, VAL)[, 2L] 182.215633 222.755943 236.844409 225.315683 236.060114 366.74375    30   b
#      ffC(X, NUM, VAL)   6.927356   6.986864   7.375294   7.078041   7.198103  10.10846    30  a
```